# Select Field Not Saving to Database, Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

This can be so simple but I'm almost burnt out and my brain is blanked. I have added a column to the users table along with others: `country`. In my User Model I have the protected fillable set for `country` and along with the others.

**My form is like this:**

```
     <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('country', 'Country') !!}
        {!! Form::select('country', ['USA', 'UK'], ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
     </div>
```

Before I go nuts, because the other columns Ive added to the users table worked so am I going mad? Should I call it a day and clearly that should work. Please help.

**The controller:**

```
public function update(@company_name)
 {
      $user = User::whereCompanyName($company_name)->firstOrFail();

    $user->fill(Input::all());

    $user->save();

    flash('You have successfully edited your profile');

    return redirect('/');
 }
```

**In my migration:**

```
$table->string('country')->unique()->nullable();
```

Comment: You need to post your controller code and perhaps the opening tag of your form please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the third argument to the Form::select() call should be the default value to the select field:

```
{{ Form::select('country', ['usa' => 'USA', Input::old('country') => 'UK'], 'uk', ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
```

the second argument is an associated array with the keys (first entry) indicating the value attributes of the option elements and the second entries the text to display. The third argument takes the first entry (or the key in the associative array) of the item you want to default to.

If you want the Input::old('country') to show your previous selection when it comes back, you need to change your controller's return statement to:

`return Redirect::to('/')->withInput()`

Comment: Sorry for the hasty answer. Edited now. Please take a look again.

Comment: It work but......although it saves now, it's not binding. Example: If I change my name in a text field, the name comes back in the field. How can I have the select field return what was selected?

Comment: In your controller redirect back withInput ( `return Redirect::to('/')->withInput()` ) and in your view change the default value with `Input::old('country')` as: `{{ Form::select('country', ['usa' => 'USA', 'uk' => 'UK'], Input::old('country'), ['class' => 'form-control']) }}`. I will edit my answer above for better view.

Comment: No need to redirect with input :) Thanks very much!

Comment: You are welcome. So you see, you are using laravel 5 :) and redirect('sometwhere') is like an alias for Redirect::to('somewhere')->withInput(). redirect() is not available in earlier versions. And beware of {!! syntax, the data input from users is not escaped.